# I'm not able to write to hosts file in android emulator

Tags: android, mount, hosts

I tried everything,

```
mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
adb remount
mount -o rw,remount,rw -t ext4 /dev/block/vda /system
```

In many cases I don't get errors when remounting and stuff, I don't get any message either, then I try something like this:

```
echo "10.0.2.2 videosup.com:5443" >> /system/etc/hosts
```

Or I do the typical push,

```
adb push ~/Desktop/hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

... and get the same error ALWAYS

```
sh: can't create /system/etc/hosts: Read-only file system
```

Tried with

- Nexus 5X API 22 Android 5.1 Lollipop
- Nexus 6 API 23 Android 6 Marshmallow

I can't believe a super simple thing like trying to get to a locally served page is getting so difficult.

Answer (score 4):

I've had issues getting this working too; however these steps work for me:

1. (Assuming Windows host) Open a Command Prompt
2. `cd %localappdata%\Android\sdk\tools`
3. Run the emulator from the command line with -writable-system flag, e.g. 
   `emulator -avd (your AVD name) -writable-system`

While the emulator is booting (wait until the Android splash appears):

4. `cd %localappdata%\Android\sdk\platform-tools`
5. `adb root` (do not proceed until this command has been successful)
6. `adb remount`
7. `adb push ~/Desktop/hosts /system/etc/hosts`

Note: You cannot add a port number to a domain name in the hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Open emulator in one terminal with writable mode

- $ `emulator  -writable-system -avd AVD_NAME // eg 5.4_FWVGA_API_22`

  Open new terminal and run following command
- $ `adb remount`
- $ `adb push C:\Temp\hosts /system/etc/`

I hope this will help others

-Neelesh